# Styling Of Wordpress Categories

Tags: css, wordpress, wp-list-categories

[This is my website](http://www.milknhny.co.uk/DVine/?page_id=19). I have added the categories, however it appears not to be `inline`. I have tried to style this in a class but this screws up the whole thing.

Do I edit the main style within the themes?

Comment: Categories where? in a sidebar?

Comment: Hi @NomikOS if u click the link above i have made a blog style template calling the last 5 posts... if u see where i have put posted by admin in ..... category... the category "uncategorised" is massively offline

Comment: Seeing at (try keystroke`CTRL-U`) source appears clear that it is a php error that is causing a break in the normal HTML output. `</div><!-- #container -->...` Check the php error log...

Comment: Hi Nomik0s i will try this. Its not showing in my aptana as an error. Weird :)

Comment: How did u spot this error, as i dont see this code in my source?

Comment: yea.... I'm also failing to see how you magically have accessed her server and are viewing the php source OR the server logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i unterstand you correctly, just add the following to your themes style.css file. This should do the trick.

```
.post-categories, .post-categories li {
    display:inline;
    padding:0;
 }
```

#### Update:

If you add this style you should see something like that. Is it what you expected? Make sure to clear your browser cache and all your styles are proper loaded.

[image]

Comment: Hi Gears,... must be my browser cache :) thankyou for your assistance

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to get rid off the extra space see my update and add the `padding:0` property.

Comment: awesome you rock @gearsdigital

Answer (score 0):

Seeing at source (try keystroke <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) appears clear that it is a php error that is causing a break in the normal HTML output. Breaks right after: `</div><!-- #container -->`...

If you can't check the php error log of your server, try output debug info directly to the screen. Put in your  `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', 1);
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```